# Access to a field with name having a special character

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a query function that returns a JSON object as below:

```
[
   {
      "ID":{
         "value":"a04c0000008KH4R",
         "display":"a04c0000008KH4R",
         "dataType":"string",
         "label":"Record ID"
      },
      "Account_vod__c":{
         "value":"001c000001BCLKfAAP",
         "display":"001c000001BCLKfAAP",
         "dataType":"string",
         "label":"Account"
      },
      "Account.ID":{
         "value":"001c000001BCLKfAAP",
         "display":"001c000001BCLKfAAP",
         "dataType":"string",
         "label":"Record ID"
      },
      "Account.FirstName":{
         "value":"Abdi",
         "display":"Abdi",
         "dataType":"string",
         "label":"FirstName"
      }
   }
]
```

In console I wanted to print the values using:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(k.data[0].Account.FirstName));
```

But it throws error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined

But for the `ID` field it is working properly:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(k.data[0].ID));
```

> a04c0000008KH4R

Is there any way to parse JSON elements, with field name having a '.' or another special character in it, like `Account.FirstName`?

Comment: Use ['Account.FirstName'] instead of Account.FirstName. Witouth the brackets it's trying to traverse into a node "Account" that doesn't exist, then looking for a sub-node "FirstName" that also does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need follow below procedure:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(k.data[0]['Account.FirstName']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You will want to use bracket notation for this rather than dot notation, which is what you are currently using. Try this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(k.data[0]["Account.FirstName"]));
```

This way, you are addressing the value the way it is stored in the JSON (with a key called "Account.FirstName"), rather than addressing it as an object of Account with a property of FirstName.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error here because you are attempting to access your object property in a way that JS interprets as another nested object. Using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) will work here, altering you object keys to not use '.' as a separator will also work.

```
const data = '[
   {
      "ID":{
         "value":"a04c0000008KH4R",
         "display":"a04c0000008KH4R",
         "dataType":"string",
         "label":"Record ID"
      },
      "Account_vod__c":{
         "value":"001c000001BCLKfAAP",
         "display":"001c000001BCLKfAAP",
         "dataType":"string",
         "label":"Account"
      },
      "Account.ID":{
         "value":"001c000001BCLKfAAP",
         "display":"001c000001BCLKfAAP",
         "dataType":"string",
         "label":"Record ID"
      },
      "Account.FirstName":{
         "value":"Abdi",
         "display":"Abdi",
         "dataType":"string",
         "label":"FirstName"
      }
   }
]';
let parse = JSON.parse(data);

/*
This will trigger the error you get:
console.log(JSON.stringify(parse.Account.FirstName));

JS will interpret this as:
    parse: {
      Account: {
        FirstName: 'value'
    }
  }
*/
console.log(JSON.stringify(parse['Account.FirstName']));
/*
JS will interpret this correctly as 
  parse: {
    'Account.FirstName': 'value'
}
```